# What should I do with multiple swapchains in DXGI?

Tags: multithreading, direct3d11, dxgi

It's confusing here. Is it that one swap chain cannot be accessed concurrently, or DXGI is completely not thread safe?

If I have 2 swap chains for 2 display on one card, what is the best way I swap them? I can hardly find any resource on multiple swap chains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417025(v=vs.85).aspx#multiple_monitors When you want to display different windows on two or more monitors, you should create two or more swapchains, each for one monitor.